# how can i predict my variables

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, prediction, statsmodels

I made a code that works with PATSY and FORMULA, but now I wanted to make 'predict' to verify the results that I found with summary. So how can i predict my variables?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm

from statsmodels.formula.api import logit, probit, poisson, ols

FNAME ="C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/table.csv"

my_data = np.genfromtxt (FNAME, delimiter = ',')


x = my_data [:,1]
d = my_data [:,4]
f=my_data[:,6]
c= my_data[:,3]
#crée un masque pour les valeurs nans
masque = ~ (np.isnan (x) | np.isnan (d) | np.isnan (f) | np.isnan (c))

x = my_data[masque, 1] - 1
d = my_data[masque, 4]
f = my_data[masque, 6]
c = my_data[masque, 3]

my_data_dict = dict (
x = x,
d = d,
f = f,
c=c

)

form = 'x ~ C(c)+C(d)+C(f)'


affair_model = logit (form, my_data_dict, manquant = 'drop')

affair_result = affair_model.fit ()

print affair_result.summary ()
```

Comment: It might be helpful for you to review [some Python basics](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/) before jumping into logistic regression.

Comment: why you say that? i learnt Python basics before jumping into logistic regression and now i have a problem in logistic regression. Also i'm trying to make your command but always i have error can you show me the complete code.

Comment: Because some of your comments below indicate that you don't understand why you got a `NameError` when you just straight-up ran `train_cols = train_cols[train_cols != 'x'][1:]`.

Comment: If I give you the complete code then you don't learn anything. Stack Overflow isn't really a site for "give me an implementation of this".

Comment: I made the code, i have just an error. ok thanx for everything

Comment: The command does not work that's why I ask you to show me the code.

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
data = df[cols_to_keep].join(dummy_ranks1.ix[:, 'c_2':]).join(dummy_ranks3.ix[:, 'd_2':]).join(dummy_ranks2.ix[:, 'f_2':])
```

you're selecting only columns `['a', 'b']`, then joining with other `DataFrame`s that don't have `x` in them.

Simply change

```
cols_to_keep = ['a', 'b']
```

to

```
cols_to_keep = ['a', 'b', 'x']
```

For one-off scripts like this, it's not a bad idea to use sanity checks with `assert` to make sure it's doing what you expect, e.g.,

```
assert 'x' in data, 'x is not a column in data'
```

Since `x` has been added back into `data` you'll need to also change `train_cols` to

```
cols = data.columns
train_cols = cols[cols != 'x'][1:]
```

Comment: yes i added x but i have this error:raise LinAlgError, 'Singular matrix'
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix

Comment: Since you've added `x` back in to `data`, you'll obviously have to make sure that `'x' is not in train_cols`.

Comment: I added x in cols_to_keep.

Comment: Since i tried tu find the prediction values of my variables... For that, i'm developping this code and i tried to apply what i found in this link http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/logistic-regression-and-python.html.